# solving the primal problem via dual

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

On pp. 248 of Boyd and Vandenberghe: suppose 1) strong duality holds, 2) the dual optimal is attained at $(\lambda^*, \nu^*)$, 3) the dual function $L(x, \lambda^*, \nu^*)$ has the unique minimizer $x^*$, 4) $x^*$ is primal feasible.

How do those assumptions imply the primal optimum is also attained and $x^*$ is in fact the primal optimal solution?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. The attainment of a unique minimizer to the dual function $L(x,\lambda^*,\nu^*)$ is one of the *assumptions*. All that they are claiming is that *if* there is a unique, primal feasible minimizer to the Lagrangian, it is also the solution to the primal problem. They are not guaranteeing that such a point exists.

Comment: Thanks for comments, Mike. Basically I am asking given those assumptions including that there is a unique, primal feasible minimizer $x^*$ to the dual function L(x, $\lambda^*$, $\nu^*$), why must the primal problem be attained at $x^*$? If there is an additional assumption that the optimal problem is attained (say, at $\tilde{x}$), then the KKT condition and unique minimizer of L(x, $\lambda^*$, $\nu^*$) will imply that $\tilde{x} = x^*$, i.e., $x^*$ is the solution to the primal problem. But I did not see such additional assumption is stated on that page. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. The minimum of the Lagrangian is the solution---that's why KKT conditions are the optimality conditions.

Comment: I meant in addition to $x^*$ is primal feasible and the unique minimizer of $L(x, \lambda^*, \nu^*)$, it also has to satisfy the complementary slackness of KKT condition ($\lambda_i^* f_i(x^*) =0, i=1,\dots, m$) to be primal optimal. But I am afraid that the complementary slackness condition is not explicitly imposed in the context. See also Prop 5.1.1 (pp.484) of Bertsekas's Nonlinear Programming.

Comment: Ah. Well, my suspicion is the complementary slackness is implied by the attainment of the minimum.

Comment: Moreover, as stated on the same page, it $x^*$ is not primal feasible, then the primal optimum is not attained. So it is possible that the primal optimum is not attained.

Comment: OK, you're back to confusing me I am afraid. Primal feasibility is an assumption above. I cannot help but think you're not parsing the implications properly.

Comment: Right. I think if there is an additional assumption that the primal minimum can be attained, then the argument can go through and the complementary slackness is implied.

Comment: No. There is not additional assumption. The statement as you have written it says that attainment *follows* from the supposed conditions. It is not assumed, it is implied. Assuming you have reproduced the statement properly, you're simply not parsing the logic correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thanks so much for the patience. Let me restate the assumption as follows: 1) strong duality holds; 2) the dual optimal is attained at $(\lambda^*, \nu^*)$; 3) $x^*$ is the unique minimizer of the dual function $L(x, \lambda^*, \nu^*)$; 4)  $x^*$ is primal feasible. Could you please let me know how the above conditions imply the primal problem is attained? thanks!

Comment: Right. So conditions (1)-(4) imply the satisfaction of complementary slackness at $(x^*,\lambda^*,\nu^*)$. I do not have a proof or you, but indeed, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's the missing part when I first read it.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, Mike! I've edited the post to clarify my question.